# Populate Kendo TreeView from Kendo Grid Data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I have both TreeView and Grid on the same page and I need to populate the TreeView from the grid data. So the flow is like this:

User selects a something from a dropdown and clicks on a button -> web service call -> populate the grid with data from web service -> populate TreeView with some massage of the grid data

The logic to populate TreeView is currently in the grid.dataSource.fetch() method like this:

```
// this function is called when user clicks on the button
function getData() {
    grid.dataSource.read();
    grid.dataSource.page(1);

    grid.dataSource.fetch(function () {
        var data = this.data();
        ... // logic to massage the data to populate TreeView
        ...
    }
}
```

However, if the user selects another thing from the dropdown and clicks on the button again, this.data() seems to have the old data (fromt the 1st time), as a result, TreeView is populated with old data.

Which is the right event/method other than fetch() I should use to put my logic in?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use kendoGrid's dataBound event. 
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-dataBound.

Here is the sample code for kendoGrid dataBound event handler:

```
function Grid_DataBound(e) {
    console.log("Grid_DataBound", e);

    var grid = e.sender;
    var dataItems = grid.dataSource.view();

    console.log(dataItems);

    var treeData = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++) {
        treeData.push({
            OrderId: dataItems[i].OrderID,
            ShipName: dataItems[i].ShipName 
        });
    }

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: treeData,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "OrderId"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Let me know if you need full sample code.